# How to remove "exit" command from Linux shell

Tags: shell, exit

I am working on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.
In this challenge I want to remove some commands from the Linux shell.

Specifically, I want to remove the `exit` command.
I want that if a user will try to exit the shell with this command, it won't be possible or maybe even send some message instead.

Any idea how can I do it ?
I searched for a file named `exit`:
`find / -name exit`

But it found only directories:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic/include/config/have/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic/include/config/have/irq/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic/include/config/have/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic/include/config/have/irq/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic/include/config/have/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic/include/config/have/irq/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic/include/config/have/exit
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic/include/config/have/irq/exit
```

**EDIT:**
I read [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-exit-command/) about using `trap` like this `trap "ENTER-COMMAND-HERE" EXIT` and I tried `trap "sh" EXIT` but it still existing the shell.

Comment: As far as I know, `exit` is a builtin (part of the shell itself, not an external application). You'd probably have to modify the source code for the shell in question. Why would you want to do such a thing as preventing a user exiting a shell session, though? (perhaps it would be better to *not* have `exit` be an alias for `logout` in interactive sessions, rather than remove the `exit` functionality.)

Comment: A bit pointless IMHO to remove the `exit` command, considering that one could send `^D` signal, either via keyboard or via `printf`, or kill the shell process. A challenge though IMHO without a satisfactory solution

Comment: There's so many ways to exit a shell session though, so I don't know what purpose disabling `exit` would serve.

Comment: While it's an odd request, I don't feel it's overly broad and could be answered (perhaps with diff/patches) if the shell(s) were specified. E235: what shells are you concerned about here?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `^D` (`VEOF`) doesn't send a signal, like `^C` (`VINTR`). It's causing the data already written to the tty to be immediately made available at the other end; if there's no such data, a read at the other end with return 0 (EOF). Also, could you please explain how you could send a `^D` to the shell from within the shell with `printf`?

Comment: @UncleBilly `^D` is actually End of Transmission, EOT, character. See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) about it. So it's a matter of `echo` or `printf` the hex value for it.  Or merely `$'\04'` in shell.  As for an example, feel free to see  one of my older answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/725208/295286

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Nope. It's exactly as I told you. Go read the termios(3) and stty(1) manpages. You can easily change it -- `stty eof z` will cause an EOF when you enter `z` twice (or once at the beginning of the line). And the question about `printf` was rhetorical; of course you cannot send an EOF to the shell from within the shell.

Comment: @UncleBilly Please re-read `termios(3)`: "(004, EOT, Ctrl-D) End-of-file character (EOF)" , and this is exactly what `$'\04'` sequence is. As for `stty eof z` , the `stty` man page says: "eof CHAR: 
CHAR will send an end of file (terminate the input)" It merely binds CHAR to sending EOF, not redefines or changes it.  And of course we can send EOF from within the shell, just like we can send other control characters that change color or title of the terminal. Feel free to ask a question here on U&L about it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I do not mean to play the smartass or humiliate you; please take some time to **test** and correct your misconceptions -- and also correct that answer you're proudly pointing to ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly  I'm always open to learning, so if you have something better to point to, feel free to do so.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy start with **testing** your false assumption that a `printf '\004'` will terminate the shell in the way a `printf '\033[31m'` will make the text red.

Comment: @UncleBilly OK, admittedly that didn't work. Nonetheless my point still stands, shell can be closed in more ways than just `exit` and even from within itself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no `exit` executable, that is one of the shell's (you don't say what shell, so I am assuming `bash`) builtin commands. As such, the only way to remove it completely is to edit the source code of the shell and recompile it (but look at [@Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493530/22222) for a better approach).

As an alternative, you could add something like this to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
alias exit='echo "You can check-out any time you like, but you can never leave!"'
```

But this is trivially easy to circumvent by anyone who knows even a little bit about *nix.

Comment: Welcome to the Hotel Bash ?!

Comment: Nope, it's `50 Ways to Leave Your Shell`

Comment: @DougO'Neal 50 Shades of Bourne ? Sorry, I'm having way too much fun here

Answer (score 17):

In addition to [what terdon said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493194/116858) (basically overriding the special built-in `exit` command with an alias, or a function for that matter), the `bash` shell also allows you to *disable* built-in commands.

To disable the `exit` built-in command:

```
enable -n exit
```

To disallow enabling it again, also disable the `enable` built-in command:

```
enable -n enable
```

Note that, just as with terdon's answer, this only affects the current shell session, unless it is implemented as part of a system-wide shell startup file.

Personally, I almost exclusively use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to exit *interactive* shell sessions. To circumvent this in `bash`, set `IGNOREEOF` to some large integer and make it read-only:

```
readonly IGNOREEOF=1000
```

This makes the shell exit after pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> 1000 times.

You could still *kill* the shell with e.g. `kill -s HUP "$$"`.  You can make the shell ignore the hangup signal with

```
trap '' HUP
```

There is no way to prevent the user from forcefully killing the shell with a `KILL` signal though, but you can remove the built-in `kill` command as above and install an overriding shell function or alias, but it would still be easy to use `/bin/kill`:

```
enable -n kill
kill () { echo 'kill: Operation not permitted' >&2; }
```

You could also exit the shell through

```
set -e
false
```

... unless you disable the `set` built-in, obviously, but that may be taking it too far, as would trying to prevent exiting by several other less obvious means (some of which, would you want to prevent them, would require modifications to the `bash` source code).

---

The issue with

```
trap 'bash' EXIT
```

is that it will spawn a new shell when the current shell exits.  That new shell is easy to exit though, because it hasn't got the trap set up, unless you install the trap as part of the shell's startup files.

This also does not prevent you from *exiting* the shell, because strictly speaking, the trap doesn't execute until the shell actually *exits*. What it gives you is a new shell.

Comment: The two `enable` commands probably could be placed into `/etc/bash.bashrc` or user's personal config file to avoid setting it for each and every shell session.

Comment: `exec true` would also effectively terminate the shell. So would setting some low limits with `ulimit`, or set `TMOUT=1`...