# Use bash EXIT trap to confirm or cancel ctrl+d

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh-tunneling, trap

Is there a simple way to require confirmation before logging out of a shell, and to prevent the shell from exiting if confirmation is denied? This would be useful to avoid accidentally terminating an SSH session used for tunneling.

The problem with `trap ... EXIT` is it still exits after completing the trap. The most promising solution I found so far is described in [confirmed exit using trap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/confirmed-exit-using-trap), which discusses ctrl+c but seems like it could be made to work for ctrl+d instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
set -o ignoreeof
```

This will cause the interactive shell to ignore `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>).

The `bash` shell will print

```
Use "exit" to leave the shell.
```

if you press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

You may also set the shell variable `IGNOREEOF` to some positive integer value.  The value determines how many times <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> has to be pressed until the shell actually exits.  The effect of doing `set -o ignoreeof` in `bash` is the same setting `IGNOREEOF=10` (and the other way around too).

The `ignoreeof` shell option is a POSIX option that should be available in all POSIX-like shells.

Related:

- [How to remove "exit" command from Linux shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493192/how-to-remove-exit-command-from-linux-shell)